# Get rows grouped by alternating column value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let's say I have the following table:

| id | engine_id | timestamp | engine_is_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1 | 1015 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 | 1010 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 | 1008 | 0 |
| 10 | 1 | 1006 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 | 1005 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 1005 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 | 1004 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 1004 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 1003 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1002 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1002 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1001 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1001 | 1 |

How to get the first and last id of entries grouped by the alternating column `engine_is_on` and also grouped by `engine_id`? Maybe an example of the desired result can clearify what I mean:

| engine_id | start_id | end_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13 | 12 |
| 1 | 10 | 6 |
| 2 | 9 | 7 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

Just for clarity's sake: for each appearance of `engine_is_on` being `0` a new row is being created for the engine_id.

SQL to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  `id` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `engine_id` INT(11),
  `timestamp` INT(11),
  `engine_is_on` TINYINT(1)
);

INSERT INTO mytable(`engine_id`, `timestamp`, `engine_is_on`) VALUES
  ('1', '1001', '1'),
  ('2', '1001', '1'),
  ('1', '1002', '1'),
  ('2', '1002', '0'),
  ('1', '1003', '0'),
  ('1', '1004', '1'),
  ('2', '1004', '1'),
  ('1', '1005', '1'),
  ('2', '1005', '1'),
  ('1', '1006', '1'),
  ('1', '1008', '0'),
  ('1', '1010', '1'),
  ('1', '1015', '1');
  
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I know that I am expected to provide what I tried, but I don't even know where to start. Or how to google correctly to guide me in the right direction.

Feel free to comment on how to make this question more understandable (including setting a proper title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum the values where `engine_is_on` is `0` then filter and aggregation:

```
select engine_id, min(id), max(id)
from (select mytable.*,
             sum(engine_is_on = 0) over (partition by engine_id order by timestamp) as grp
      from mytable
     ) t
where engine_is_on = 1
group by engine_id, grp;
```